# fetching output of git command in a windows bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

I would like to get the output of the following command in the context of a windows bat file:

`git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs --format="%(refname:short)" --count=1`

To do so, I wrote the following bat file:

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in ('git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs --format="%(refname:short)" --count=1') do set last=%%a
echo "%last%"
```

However, when I run that file my `last` variable is set to `:short)`. I tried to escape the parenthesis but it did not help. I guess that the problem comes from the handling of the colon but I do not find any way to get through. Would you have any idea?

Comment: In a batch file you need to escape the special character `%`. Unlike  most  other characters, which are escaped with a caret, _(`^`)_, a percent character is escaped by doubling it. Therefore you should be using `%%(refname:short)`. Because the command which is enclosed within the parentheses is run within another cmd instance, the content is passed to that instance. Because of that you will need to escape some other characters too, i.e. your `=` characters, wich need the carets, i.e. `-sort^=-committerdate refs --format^="%%(refname:short)" --count^=1`.

Comment: may thanks for the clear explanation